# Retrieving details of user on activity restart

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences

I have a login activity on app start and I need to check if use has used this app before and then I need to place the username and his password entered recently.

For this I have used shared preferences and used as shown below:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {

       username= usernameET.getText().toString();
       password= passwordET.getText().toString();

       SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
       data.edit().putString("username", username).commit();
       data.edit().putString("password", password).commit();
    }
});
```

Now I'm getting these values on app restart as shown below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);
       SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
       String storedUsername = data.getString("username", "");
       String storedPassword = data.getString("password", "");
      if (storedUsername != null && storedPassword != null) {
          usernameET.setText(storedUsername);
          passwordET.setText(storedPassword);
        } else {

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coder, what is your issue? This is not working? 
Please, tell us what is happening.

The implementation with SharedPreference would be my suggestion for you, is it not working?

I made a very simple implemention here and it works as usual...

On the onCreate:

```
SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
String storedUsername = data.getString("username", "");
String storedPassword = data.getString("password", "");
Toast.makeText(this, "saved Strings, user = " + storedUsername + "  pass = " + storedPassword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

On the click of an ImageButton

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
data.edit().putString("username", "carlos").commit();
data.edit().putString("password", "password").commit();
}
```

Sounds like you are not setting the content on the SharedPreferences. Could you please make sure the action is executed?

Comment: Unfortunatly I do not have 50 rep (necessary to make a comment), so this was the only reason to post my question as an answer. Thanks for clarifying, i am looking at some projects I have here now.

Comment: I made a very simple implemention here and it works as usual...  Sounds like you are not setting the content on the SharedPreferences. Could you please make sure the action is executed?

Comment: @carlosmaciel-can you share the link or the demo you have done ?

Comment: I updated my original answer, hope that it helps you

Comment: @carlosmaciel- +1.Thanks for your time..I dont know what hppnd with my code and yours worked perfectly gud :)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't really see a question asked but...

data.getString is going to return the default value if it is not set, which you're setting as a blank string("").  Either change your if:

```
if (!storedUsername.equals("") && !storedPassword.equals(""))
```

or change your default value to null

```
String storedUsername = data.getString("username", null);
String storedPassword = data.getString("password", null);
```

Comment: @user1732917-It gives me the same null value and does this "" and null are not the same ?